# ClassNotFoundException when trying to connect to a postgres database through a scala/spark application

Tags: java, scala, jdbc, sbt, classnotfoundexception

I need to connect to a postgres database through a scala/spark app. It works perfectly when I run it in my IDE however, I am getting the following log message when I try to run the packaged executable jar with this command:

Triggering the executable jar with:

```
java -cp HighestPerformingCampaign-assembly-1.0.jar com.scala.Executor
```

Exeception thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: jdbc. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:689)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:743)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:266)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:226)
            at com.scala.Executor$.findHighestCampaign(Executor.scala:31)
            at com.scala.Executor$.main(Executor.scala:15)
            at com.scala.Executor.main(Executor.scala)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdbc.DefaultSource
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:663)
            at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSo`enter code here`urce$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:663)
            at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:663)
            ... 6 more
```

My build.sbt file is set up as follows:

```
name := "HighestPerformingCampaign"

version := "1.0"

crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.12", "2.12.12")

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.1.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.1.1"

libraryDependencies +=  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1102-jdbc41"

mainClass := Some("com.scala.Executor")
assemblyJarName in assembly := "HighestPerformingCampaign-assembly-1.0.jar"
```

and I am using the sbt-assembly plugin, which is stored under the project folder, to generate the jar:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.15.0")
```

Is there something that I'm missing here which is preventing the driver from getting added to the packaged jar? My connection details are specified as follows also:

```
val df = spark
      .sqlContext
      .read
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:postgres")
      .option("user", "postgres")
      .option("password", "postgres")
      .option("query", query)
      .load()
```

Comment: is this resolved? facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your jar if it has the required classes using `jar -tf HighestPerformingCampaign-assembly-1.0.jar`. If it does not contain the required class `jdbc.DefaultSource` (which should be the case), it means the fat / packaged jar is not getting built as expected. I would suggest instead of creating this fat jar, you can create `Artifacts` from the IDE (in Intellij it's at `Project Settings -> Artifacts` ) , which is basically creates and puts all the dependent jars under some Artifacts root directory, and then provide the path of this directory to the java command like `java -cp HighestPerformingCampaign-assembly-1.0.jar:<absolute path to artifact root> com.scala.Executor`

Comment: I ran 'jar -tf HighestPerformingCampaign-assembly-1.0.jar' and saw driver classes are referenced: org/postgresql/Driver$1.class,
org/postgresql/Driver$ConnectThread.class,
org/postgresql/Driver.class
However, I am continually getting this error now: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver. I tried adding     Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver") but no luck. Any idea how I can resolve this please?